# Is every repeatedly nested monads useful?

Tags: haskell, io, monads

By the title, I mean types like `Monad m => m (m a)`.

When the structure of a monad is simple, I can easily think of a usage of such type:

- `[[a]]`, which is a multidimensional list
- `Maybe (Maybe a)`, which is a type adjoined by two error states
- `Either e (Either e a)`, which is like above, but with messages
- `Monoid m => (m,(m,a))`, which is a writer monad with two things to write over
- `r -> r -> a`, which is a reader monad with two things to read from
- `Identity (Identity a)`, which is still the identity monad
- `Complex (Complex a)`, which is a 2-by-2 matrix

But it goes haywire in my mind if I think about the following types:

- `ReadP (ReadP a)`? Why would it be useful when `ReadP` isn't an instance of `Read`?
- `ReadPrec (ReadPrec a)`? Like above?
- `Monad m => Kleisli m a (Kleisli m a b)`?
- `IO (IO a)`!? This **must** be useful. It just is too hard to think about it.
- `forall s. ST s (ST s a)`!? This should be like the above.

Is there a practical use for such types? Especially for the `IO` one?

On the second thought, I might need to randomly pick an `IO` action. That's an example of `IO (IO a)` which focuses on inputs. What about one focusing on outputs?

Comment: `IO (IO a)` could be an action which asynchronously starts some operation which produces `a`, and gives back a result of type `IO a` which can be used to wait for the `a` to be available.

Comment: See slide 33 here https://speakerdeck.com/ajnsit/supercharged-imperative-programming-with-haskell-and-fp?slide=33 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQfYOZljqoI&feature=youtu.be&t=1197 for an example of the usefulness of `IO (IO ())`. It's used to represent two-phase "asking for an action, actually performing it" plans that can be combined using `Monoid`.

Comment: `ReadP (ReadP a)` could represent a parser that reads a schema file for type `a` and returns another parser that actually reads `a` according to the schema. These kinds of "nestings" can be useful even if the type constructor is not a `Monad`, but only `Applicative`. A useful fact is that the composition (nesting) of two `Applicative`s is again an `Applicative` http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html#t:Compose

Comment: GHC uses nested parsers too. Conceptually, `P (P a)` (where `P` is a parser) is as such that the outer layer actually parses syntax and consumes input and then the inner layer validates it. The note in the source says this is used to disambiguate parses: a parser can return multiple parsers if the parse is ambiguous, and then the calling code can deal with that. Having all the possibilities is used to construct helpful error messages. In reality, the inner `P` is a slightly different type than `P`, which the source says is "for clarity", because that enforces that it consumes no input.

Answer (score 2):

In some sense, a monad can be thought of as a functor in which layers can be collapsed.

If the `Monad` class were defined more like the category-theory definition, it would look like

```
class Applicative m => Monad m where
    return ::  a -> m a
    join :: m (m a) -> m a
```

Using `fmap` with a function of type `a -> m b` results in a function of type `m a -> m (m b)`. `join` is used to eliminate one layer of monad from the result. Since that's a common thing to do, one might define a function that does it.

```
foo :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
foo f ma = join (fmap f ma)
```

If you look carefully, you'll recognize `foo` as `>>=` with its arguments flipped.

```
foo = flip (>>=)
```

Since `>>=` is used more than `join` would be, the typeclass definition is

```
class Applicative m => Monad m where
    return :: a -> m a
    (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

and `join` is defined as a separate function

```
join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
join mma = mma >>= id
```

Answer (score 0):

Does not matter.

Monads are monads precisely because for every  `Monad ( Monad a )` we can always get `Monad a`. Such operation is called "join" and it's alternative operation to "bind" that could form definition of Monad. Haskell uses "bind" because its much more useful for composing monadic code :)
(join can be implemented with bind, and bind with join - they are equivalent)

> Does not matter

Is actually small lie, since ability to form `Monad ( Monad a )` is also de facto part of what makes Monads monads. With `Monad (Monad a)` being transitional representation in some operations.

Full answer is:  Yes, because that enables Monads. Though `Monad ( Monad a )` can have extra "domain" meaning as you list for some of the Monads ;)